# iOS UIImage being rotated when after going through CIFilter

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-image

I'm working with filtering images that I'm taking with the camera.  I pass the image I get from the camera through the below method.  Which I have the returned `UIImage` sent to a `UIImageView`.  For some reason when it passes through this method the image is getting rotated. What am I doing wrong?

```
    - (UIImage *) applyFilterToImage:(UIImage *)image withFilter:(NSString *)filterName {

    beginImage = [[[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
    context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
    outputImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);

    return scaleAndRotateImage(newImg);
}
```

Comment: If all you wish to do is apply a sepia tone filter to an image and display it onscreen or save it as a UIImage, I might suggest this as an alternative to Core Image: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . I'm about 4X faster than Core Image for still image processing, even faster if you just need to display to a view, and I have a simpler API for this process. My sepia tone is a slightly different hue than Core Image's, but that can be tweaked.

Comment: I was just looking at your library last night.  It is very nice.  I will be utilizing many more filter, I just put SepiaTone in for testing.

Comment: I think I'm down to just 9 filters that Core Image has over me on iOS, and 4 blend modes. However, I have many filters (such as blurs and convolutions) that Core Image currently lacks on iOS. You also can write your own custom ones.