# Filter applied to UIImage and rotated image using CIFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cifilter

When I applied to a `UIImage` a filter the result of the image is that it is rotated! I have tried this:

```
var filterNames: [String] = ["CIPhotoEffectTonal","CIPhotoEffectNoir","CIMaximumComponent","CIMinimumComponent","CIDotScreen", "CISepiaTone", "CIFalseColor", "CIColorInvert", "CIColorPosterize", "CIPhotoEffectChrome", "CIPhotoEffectInstant"]

    let CIfilterName = filterNames[indexPath.row]
    print(CIfilterName)

    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    let startImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: CIfilterName)
    filter!.setDefaults()

    filter!.setValue(startImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let filteredImageData = filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)

    let originalOrientation: UIImageOrientation = (imageView.image?.imageOrientation)!
    let originalScale: CGFloat = (imageView.image?.scale)!
    let newPtImage: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithCGImage(filteredImageRef, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
    imageView.image = newPtImage

    imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef);
```

The last part of scale is what I have tried but I am showing that part of the code so you can see what I have done wrong or I don't know what.

I found this answer but it is in Objective-c: [Stackoverflow answer in obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913939/ios-uiimage-being-rotated-when-after-going-through-cifilter)

Comment: Can you change the final scaling to `UIImageOrientation.Up`? Let me know what happen

Comment: I deleted the last part of the code, should I keep it?

Comment: Come to [NSChat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [**`UIImageOrientation`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImageOrientation) to fix this issue, but I definitely recommend `switch` ([**Github**](https://gist.github.com/alex-cellcity/1531596) Sample) statement with extension, cause later when the photo gets uploaded into the server it might also change its orientation again.

#### Example:

```
UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem arise when image-height is greater than image-width so if your image's height is greater than width then you should resize the image by swapping image height and width with each other before applying CIFilter....